# Which is the longest and shortest Bavli Talmud tractate in terms of actual Talmud text?

Tags: talmud-gemara, statistics

I see that we have several questions related to the longest and shortest *masechta* in terms of pages (dapim).

Many Gemarah pages have little text - some less than 10 lines because the Talmud text is surrounded by the commentaries on the outside borders. Likewise, some have little commentary.

My question, then, is which tractate has the most Talmud text (least commentary) and which has the least Talmud text (most commentary.)

I am not seeking a page calculation, here, as that would be irrelevant. I'm just looking for most and least text.

If there is a ranked list online or otherwise, please inform!